# Problemas con la suma de los valores de un arreglo

Tags: php

El problema que tengo es que no suma los valores de varios arreglos contenido en un arreglo, no sé porque aqui el codigo:

```
<?php
    function solution($number) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
                $multiplo = $i * $number;
                $arreglo = [];
                $arreglo[$i] = str_split($multiplo);
                print_r(array_sum(array_column($arreglo, '0')));
            }
        }
    solution('3');
?>
```

Comment: El resultado es 036 cuando esos valores deben sumarse entre si

Comment: Por favor explica mejor tu pregunta. No entiendo para que haces todo eso en tu código. ¿Buscas que solution('3') imprima **9**? ¿Que resultado esperas?

Comment: Si enumeramos todos los números naturales por debajo de 10 que son múltiplos de 3 o 5, obtenemos 3, 5, 6 y 9. La suma de estos múltiplos es 23.

Termine la solución para que devuelva la suma de todos los múltiplos de 3 o 5 debajo del número ingresado.

Comment: Ese es un ejercicio, no pido que me hagan todo el ejercicio, solo necesito que se me sume los valores del arreglo para proceder a terminar el programa

Comment: Date cuenta que en cada iteración estas imprimiendo e inicializando el array. De todas maneras lo que planteas y la solucion que tienes no tienen nada que ver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es la forma de que sume los elementos del array según lo rellenas en tu for, a la izq del igual los elementos del array y a la derecha su suma. Para ello debes iniciar el array donde vas a almacenar los números a sumar fuera del bucle, y la suma se realiza después del bucle, que es cuando ya tienes relleno el array. Si inicias el array dentro del bucle tendrá en cada ciclo un único elemento, y la suma de un elemento es ese elemento, de ahi el resultado que tenías.

Espero que con esto ya puedas avanzar en tu ejercicio.

```
    function solution($number) {
       $arreglo = array();
       for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
          $arreglo[$i] = $i * $number;
          print_r($arreglo[$i]);
       }
       print_r("=");
       print_r(array_sum($arreglo));
   }
solution('3');
//036=9
```

Comment: Gracias, ahora como marco la pregunta como resuelta en este foro?

Comment: No hay de que. Al lado de la respuesta tienes un check, haces click para que se ponga verde y ya está.